# Redux state doesn't persist on refresh

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a header component where the user details are fetched and then stored in redux.

Now, in the user profile edit page, I am connecting the same reducer to fetch user details.

```
export default connect(state => ({
  ...state.user,
}),{
  ...actions,
})(MyProfile);
```

this.props.user contains the user object.

The problem is that, when the page is refreshed, redux state doesn't persist and there is no user object in props.

What is the correct way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you can do is by using [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist).Update your store to use persisted reducer like so :

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage' // defaults to localStorage for web and AsyncStorage for react-native

import rootReducer from './reducers'

const persistConfig = {
   key: 'root',
   storage,
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

export default () => {
   let store = createStore(persistedReducer)
   let persistor = persistStore(store)
   return { store, persistor }
}
```

It uses `localStorage` to store the data. So next time when you refresh the page it will rehydrate the store from localStorage.

Comment: I can only feed the data once, it never get updated, any idea why?